# If the join of two degrees compute one of their jumps, what can we say about the jump of the other degree?

Tags: computability-theory, turing-machines

Let $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ be two Turing degrees such that $\mathbf{a'} = \mathbf{a} \oplus \mathbf{b}$. Must it be the case that $\mathbf{a'} \leq \mathbf{b'}$? What if in addition, we know that $\mathbf{b'} \leq \mathbf{a'}$?

This seems to be a basic fact if true, but I cannot see how to easily prove it in general, which leads me to think it should be false. Is there a known counterexample then?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not true in general. If ${\bf a}$ is sufficiently Cohen generic then ${\bf a}\oplus{\bf 0'}\equiv_T{\bf a}'$, so a fortiori we get ${\bf a}\oplus {\bf b}'\ge_T{\bf a}'$ for any ${\bf b}$ whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean that in this case, $\mathbf{0''} \not\geq \mathbf{a'}$? What if we have the additional condition? Is $\mathbf{a'} \geq \mathbf{0''}$?

Comment: @Zoorado If ${\bf a}$ is sufficiently Cohen generic, say $17$-generic, both ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf a}'$ will be Turing-incomparable with ${\bf 0}''$. I'm not sure about the additional condition, but I suspect that the answer remains negative.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Noah's answer, jump-inversion allows you to take any degree ${\bf d} \ge {\bf 0}'$ and obtain a 1-generic ${\bf a}$ with ${\bf a}' = {\bf a}\oplus {\bf 0}' = {\bf d}$.  In particular, with ${\bf d} = {\bf 0}^{(3)}$ we have a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extreme example. Suppose that $0^{\sharp}$ exists. Then for any nonrecursive real $b\in L$, by Posner-Robinson theorem, there is a 1-generic real $a$ so that $0^{\sharp}\equiv_T a\oplus b\equiv_T a'$. Then for whatever "simply defined'' jump operator $J$, $J(b)$ would be computed by $a'$ but not computes even $a$.  This can be generalized to arbitrary defined "jump operator'' under certain set theory axioms.